# Get dimensions of RelativeLayout at run-time

Tags: java, android, runtime, android-relativelayout, dimension

I am trying to get the dimensions of the width and height in pixels of the RelativeLayout that I highlighted in red in the below picture.

[image]

In my code below, for testing purposes, I am setting the text of the Button in the RelativeLayout to the width of the whole layout (circled in blue in the picture).  In the picture you can see the width is returning the value of 0.  Below is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    puzzleRL = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

    puzzleLayout();

    puzzleRL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            puzzleRL.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            puzzleWidth = puzzleRL.getWidth();
            puzzleHeight = puzzleRL.getHeight();
        }
    });

    levelCounter.setText("" + puzzleWidth);

    setContentView(relativelayout);
}

public void puzzleLayout() {

    // define puzzle space boundaries
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view0.getId());
    params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view3.getId());
    relativelayout.addView(puzzleRL, params0);

}
```

I've looked around and it seems like I need to utilize the `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` method, which I have.  But it still returns 0 as the width.  I even tried putting all of my declarations from my `onCreate()` method and all of the layout code that is currently in the `puzzleLayout()` method into the `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` method and but it still didn't return the correct thing.

Is `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` the incorrect way to do this?  Or am I possibly getting the dimensions `getWidth()/getHeight()` incorrectly?

**EDIT**
I have altered my code to reflect suggestions from commenters.  However, the `levelCounter` TextView is still outputting 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can see from code `puzzleRL` layout has nothing inside!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width and height of a Layout, when they are not explicitly defined, are given only after all children are drawn.

This is the code i use:

```
//layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

    // Ensure you call it only once :
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        width = layout.getWidth();// width must be declare as a field
        height = layout.getHeight;// height must be declare as a field
        levelCounter.setText("" + width);´
    }
});
```

It must be in onCreate.

Comment: What is the variable `layout` in your code?  Should that be `relativelayout` instead?  EDIT:  Actually, I'm thinking `layout` should be `puzzleRL` instead?

Comment: Is the layout that you want to know width and height

Comment: It is saying that `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)` is deprecated.  Trying to find quickly to what it changed.

Comment: At api 16 this method was renamed to removeOnGlobalLayoutListener. You can test for what api is in use and code according

Comment: Updated my opening post with your code you suggested.  The output is still 0 though.

Comment: Try move `levelCounter.setText("" + puzzleWidth);` to after `setContentView(relativelayout);`. If no results try change `puzzleRL.getViewTreeObserver()` to `relativelayout.getViewTreeObserver()` keeping `puzzleWidth = puzzleRL.getWidth();` and `puzzleRL.getHeight;`

Comment: Please ignore first line of my last comment. ´levelCounter.setText("" + puzzleWidth);´ must be moved inside `onGlobalLayout()` after `puzzleHeight = puzzleRL.getHeight();`. `onGlobalLayout()` is only called after onCreate.

Comment: Yes!  Your last comment worked perfectly.  If you would, edit your post so people in the future can just see the answer there instead of having to read all these comments we've posted underneath.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move your code to onResume(), rather than keeping it in onWindowsFocusChanged(), because the latter is called whenever the activity changes focus (gains or loses focus).
Don't forget to execute your code just once using a flag (or similar). Otherwise you will recreate all the buttons everytime.

By the way, you may want to try:

```
bList[0].setText(String.valueOf(w));
```

Edit:
All the cretion code should be in onCreate().
Inside onResume() which is part of the visible phase of an activity, you can gt the dimension:

```
puzzleRL.measure(0, 0);
puzzleRL.getMeasuredHeight();
puzzleRL.getMeasuredWidth();
```

You can also post a delayed Runnable (500ms delay) to a Handler to do the measurement after onResume.
Hope it works for you.